# String to char in switch function, java

Tags: java, types

I am new to programming and I am trying to write a code for frequency analysis of a sentence. I have a problem, that in switch statement it is char and in case it is string, which does not work together. I have an int variables for each letter in alphabet and i want to make a case to each letter, which will count it. Can someone help me how to make same variable type in both

```
    for (int index = 0; index <= text.length();index++) {
        switch (text.charAt(index)) {

        case "a" : acount++;break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try case 'a' instead of case "a"

Comment: Also `index < text.length()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++) {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))) {
        case 'a':
            acountA++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            acountB++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Characters must be enlosed in single quotes and string in double quotes. Also interate till less than text length.

```
for (int index = 0; index < text.length();index++) {

      switch (text.charAt(index)) {

      case 'a' : acount++;break;

      }
  }
```